# Autonomous linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given $K(0) = 0,\!2P$. I'm supposed to solve the ODE

$$ \frac{dK}{dt} = \lambda(P-K)$$

I have tried to seperate and integrate both sides

$$ \int \frac{1}{P-K} dK = \int \lambda \space dt$$

to get

$$\ln(P-K) = \lambda t + C$$

and then solve for $K$

$$ e^{\ln(P-K)} = P-K=e^{\lambda t + C}$$
$$ -(-K) = -(-P + e^{\lambda t + C})$$
$$ K = P - e^{\lambda t + C}$$

is that about right for the general solution? And where I'm really stuck is how do I proceed to find the particular solution?

Comment: $\ln (P - K) = \lambda t + C$ should be $- \ln (P - K) = \lambda t + C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\ln (P - K) = \lambda t + C$ should be $- \ln (P - K) = \lambda t + C$ because you need to use the substitution $u = P - K$ so that $du =  - dK$. To find the particular solution use the initial data. Set $t = 0$ and $K = 0.2P$ to solve for $C$, since $K(0) = 0.2P$.